# DLL is deleted from bin when starting ASP.NET Core website for the second time

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dll, task-parallel-library

I am developing an ASP.NET Core Web-API targeting .NET Framework 4.7.

A project in my solution is dependent on [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow v4.9.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) (added as a nuget package).

These steps reproduce my issue:

1. Clean solution
2. Run website (bin folder has System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll)
3. Stop website (bin folder has System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll)
4. Run website (System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll is DELETED from bin folder).

On step 4 the site throws an FileNotFoundException:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is of course because the file is deleted from the bin folder for the web site. The .dll is still in the bin folder for the project referencing it.

Who/what is deleting the file?
If i do a clean and build or "Rebuild", the .dll is copied into the bin folder again and the website runs the first time.

If I stop and restart it, the file is deleted again.

If I only stop and "Build" solution, the file is NOT deleted. Only when I run the website.

I have tried to run without debugger, but still same issue.

EDIT:

I have used Process Monitor to find that it is "MSBuild.exe" that is deleting the file. Why would it do that?

Comment: Learn Process Monitor from SysInternals and use it to monitor your file system. Then the culprit will reveal itself.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi , I have updated my Q with the findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

There was another project in my solution that referenced the older "Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow" v.4.5.24 nuget package to use Dataflow.

Once I uninstalled this old nuget package and added "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" v4.9.0, MSBuild did not delete my file anymore.

Still a bit weird that it only deleted the file on the second run, but it works now!